# Downloading dataset python course Brandon Rhodes

Tags: python, pandas, build, rhodes

I have been trying hard to download the data set of the following pandas tutorial:
https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pycon-pandas-tutorial

I am stuck at the following code:
build/BUILD.sh

I get the following error:
'build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have tried to google the answer but the only hits I got related to the build command were quite technical. I am using conda, and I have tried to update conda to the newest version but that did not help.

I also tried the alternative way of getting the data set (FTP links at the bottom of the page), but those links do not work. Nothing happens in my browser.
The tutorial is quite old - 2015, so maybe the syntax did change?

Comment: I assume you're using Windows? a .sh file won't work for you on Windows. Plus you would need to use ./build/BUILD.sh if it were a file Windows can run, because it wouldn't find it in your PATH.

Comment: You will need to download the files from the FTP links at the bottom. Be sure you are using a browser or other program that can handle FTP: newer Chrome, Edge and Firefox removed/are removing support for FTP.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpfull, managed to get the data from the FTP links using an older browser!